# StytchB2B prebuilt ui not showing SSO button in Next.js

Tags: next.js, stytch

I've added the StytchB2B component from @stytch/nextjs/b2b  with the following config

```
  config: {
    authFlowType: AuthFlowType.Organization,
    products: [B2BProducts.sso, B2BProducts.oauth],
    oauthOptions: {
      discoveryRedirectURL: REDIRECT_URL,
      providers: ['google', 'microsoft']
    },
    ssoOptions: {
      loginRedirectURL: REDIRECT_URL,
      signupRedirectURL: REDIRECT_URL
    },
  },
```

Following is a screenshot of the rendered UI, which isn't rendering the SSO button. I'm probably missing something. Any help would be appreciated.
[image: Screenshot of Rendered UI]